# what's the purpose of typename assignment inside templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have come across this piece of code (I'm trying to include all details in case I'm missing something):

```
template< typename TYPE = TYPE_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name,
          typename KIND = KIND_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void bar(TYPE& t, KIND& k) = 0;
};
```

And the part I don't understand is the assignments inside the template:

```
template <typename TYPE = TYPE_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name, ..
```

I have been trying to understand the effect of this but so far I couldn't produce any. Here are some stuff I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    cout << typeid(t).name() << " ";
}

template<typename T = int>
void bar(T t) {
    cout << typeid(t).name() << " ";
}

template<typename T = double>
void baz(T t) {
    cout << typeid(t).name() << " ";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\nfoo: ";
    foo(3); foo<int>(3); foo<double>(3);
    cout << "\nbar: ";
    bar(3); bar<int>(3); bar<double>(3);
    cout << "\nbaz: ";
    baz(3); baz<int>(3); baz<double>(3);
    return 0;
}
```

prints out:

```
foo: i i d
bar: i i d
baz: i i d
```

So my question is:

1. What is the effect of assignment inside `template`?
2. What is the purpose of using it in the above example?
3. There is no third question.

Any help is appreciated..

**EDIT** turned out functions are only compilable with c++11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called 'default template argument' and specifies which type is used, when none is specified - alike default function parameters. This technique is widely used for classes - look at definition of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and you will see they have multiple default type parameters.

Best use for default type parameters for function templates is when type argument cannot be easily deduced from actual arguments, and it is not specified explicitly - then compiler will use default one. In your example there is no need for default types, because it can be easily deduced from actual call parameters.

Until C++0x default type parameters were allowed only for class templates - they were not possible to use with function templates. With C++0x it changed, but some older compilers (for example Visual C++ 2008) would not let you to use them.

Comment: Nitpicking: `std::string` does not have any template parameter, since it's a `typedef` (for `std::basic_string<char>`); what you are talking about is probably `std::basic_string`, which has default values (based on the character type) for the traits and allocator parameters.

Comment: +1 for making me realize I had forgotten my `-std=c++0x` switch on

Answer (score 7):

These are not assignments but rather “default values” for the type arguments of the template, much like there is a similar syntax for default value arguments of functions. They are used when an explicit argument is not specified.

For `bar` and `baz` function templates in your example, it makes no sense because for these functions, `T` will be derived from the specified arguments.

Comment: I thought so but why does `baz(3)` returns `i`?

Comment: Because `3` is `int` literal?

Comment: As I said, for `bar` and `baz` the default you specified is never used. They are always instantiated according to the types of actual parameters they're called with, so the call to `baz(3)` actually means `baz<int>(3)`.

Comment: @Joker_vD so the type is inferred even if I don't give any parameters? so when does the 'default values' ever used?

Comment: 1. They are used for classes, where types are never inferred. `class C<typename T=int>` can be instantiated as `C<>`, and that will mean `C<int>`.
2. They are also used for functions where not all type arguements can be inferred from their call. For example: `template<typename T=SomeClass> T * make_object() { return new T(); }` — you can't have `T` inferred from the call, so you have to call it as `make_object<SomeClass>()`, but the default value lets you omit `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 6):

A function-template may not be the best construct to demonstrate default template arguments.  Here's something similar with template-structs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T = int>
struct foo {
   static void f() {
      std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\t";
   }
};

template<typename T = double>
struct bar {
   static void f() {
      std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\t";
   }
};

int main() {
  foo<>::f(); foo<int>::f();  foo<double>::f();  std::cout << std::endl;
  bar<>::f(); bar<int>::f();  bar<double>::f();  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Running this, I get:

```
% ./a.out 
i   i   d   
d   i   d
```

Comment: Default template arguments don't (usally) make sense with function because the template-type is implied by the function-argument type.  With classes and structs, you have to either explicitly define the type, or use the default type (if provided).

Answer (score 2):

1. The "assignments" inside the template parameter list are default parameters, just as in function parameter lists. That means in your example, `Foo<>` is the same as `Foo<TYPE_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name, KIND_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name>`, and `Foo<int>` is the same as `Foo<int, KIND_with_an_arbitrarily_long_name>`.
2. It will not be used in your examples. You don't use `Foo` at all, and the parameters of `baz` and `bar` will always be deduced by the compiler from the given arguments.

Comment: (1) don't mind the `Foo` for function examples, functions are just for demonstration whereas `Foo` was the actual code I saw (2) so when does the 'default parameters' ever used if they are inferred when I don't specify anything and overridden when I specify something?

Comment: They are inferred _in your examples_ because your examples are functions. Since the code you saw in the wild was actually the class template `Foo`, consider `Foo<>` and `Foo<int>` which I mentioned above as examples. - or look at the answer provided by @eduffy

Answer (score 1):

These are default template arguments. You can use template default arguments to simplify their usage.

When you have two template parameters, for example, and give the last one a default type, you must specify only one type.

[`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), for example, is defined as

```
template < class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

Here you have a default template argument for `Allocator`, so you can define vectors with just one argument

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

Answer (score -3):

What you are looking for is "Template Specialization"

Here's a link to some [Example/Explanation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/explicit_specialization.htm)

Comment: Explicit template specialization is not involved here, they are just default template parameters.