# "template <class _Tp, class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp) >" what = means?

Tags: c++

when i see stl source code, i see some code,i couldn't understand?

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp) >
class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc> 
{
  // requirements:

  __STL_CLASS_REQUIRES(_Tp, _Assignable);
  ....
}
```

so, the question is what `=` means in `template <class _Tp, class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp) >`?

can i understand `=` just like using keywords:

```
using _Alloc = class __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp)
```

Comment: See [default template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` indicates a default template argument.

e.g.

```
template <class Foo = std::string>
class Bar
```

means "use `std::string` if no argument is supplied. You could use `Bar` like this:

```
Bar b;
```

which would be equal to

```
Bar<std::string> b;
```

---

In your case,

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp) >
class vector
```

means

> by default, use `__STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_TP)` if nothing else is specified

allowing you to write

```
vector<int> v;
```

instead of having to write

```
vector<int, __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(int)> v;
```

which would be *way more* verbose.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566409/7571171) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp)` means that the template accepts a parameter `_Alloc` , and if you don't supply one then the default `__STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Tp)` will be used.

The `=` means "use by default".